# Latitude and Longitude of the current location

Tags: android

How i can get the latitude and longitude of the current location, from android?

Comment: Here's your answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an)

Comment: +1. In fact I'm voting to close this question because it is an exact duplicate of that other question.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an exact duplicate, because that question is asking how to get the location, this is asking for lat/long specifically. Granted, location gives the lat/long when you ask for it, but still. This is like another step that they don't cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the LocationListener class to get the coordinates while on the move.

use the following to get the coordiates when not on the move.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);  

if(location == null){
    LAT = 0.0;
    LONG = 0.0;
    loc.setText("No Location");
}
```

for an indepth discussion --

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39239/1954

Comment: Getting null pointer Exception while use location.getLatitude();location.getLoongitude();

Comment: you probably haven't pushed the lat and long from DDMS. anyway can you post your code.