# How do I get the country code of a user on Android?

Tags: java, android, localization, geolocation

How can I retrieve a user's country code on Android? Do I need permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714418/13082664

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the country code stored in the sim card of the phone you can try

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
```

You can try also:

```
 Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
 locale.getCountry();
```

This returns the data from the language/Country stated from the user and not the physical location.

Comment: I don´t get this kind of answers. What about wifi devices? What about devices without sim? what about devices with a sim but in a foreign country?

Answer (score 1):

[Latitude and Longitude of the current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862731/latitude-and-longitude-of-the-current-location)

Will get you the latitude and longitude.

I'd suggest using Google Map's reverse geocoding for getting the country, and then using a lookup table if you want to get some country code (I'd assume the country's telephone code, but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice from the: [Localization documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)
recommends using the Locale set here:

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

Furthermore, this field is also mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2). You can then call getCountry() on it to obtain the two-letter uppercase ISO country code as defined by ISO 3166-1.  **Note** that java doc says it may return an empty String if the Locale doesn't correspond to specific country.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function. It's returning your country ISO code:

```
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        public String getSimCountryIso() {

    return telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();

}
```

Add permission below into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```